# K8s service LB to external services w/ nginx-ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

Is it possible to configure k8s nginx-ingress as a LB to have a K8s Service actively connect to external backend hosted on external hosts/ports (where one will be enabled at a time, connecting back to the cluster service)?

Similar to envoy proxy? This is on vanilla K8s, on-prem.

So rather than balance load from

```sh
client -> cluster -> service.
```

I am looking for

```sh
service -> nginx-ingress -> external-backend.
```

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/629#issue-222930691
Might that be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a Kubernetes `Service` with no `selector`. Then you need to define a `Endpoint`. You can put the IP and port in the Endpoint. Normally you do not define Endpoints for Services but because the Service will not have a `Selector` you will need to provide an Endpoint with the same name as the Service.

Then you point the Ingress to the Service.

Here's an example that exposes an Ingress on the cluster and sends the traffic to 192.168.88.1 on TCP 8081.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: router
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8081
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: router
  namespace: default
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 192.168.88.1
      - ip: 192.168.88.2 # As per question below
    ports:
      - port: 8081
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: router
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my-router.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: router
              servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Can I have many (more than one) Endpoint for the single Service?

Comment: @jj2424 sure, it would not be another `Endpoint` object but rather another IP. I'll add it above but to be clear there can only be only `Endpoint` per `Service`

Answer (score 0):

While defining ingress use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet` annotation. Enable also proxy protocol using `use-proxy-protocol: "true"`.

Using this annotation you can add additional configuration to the NGINX location.

Please take a look:  [ingress-nginx-issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/629#issue-222930691), [advanced-configuration-with-annotations](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/).