# How do configure my k8s nginx controller to external service running somewhere else

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, load-balancing

I have AKS running with nginx controller. I am looking to setup ingress reverse proxy so customer accessing the url will be able to a service running on VM outside AKS.

I have tried the below article - [K8s service LB to external services w/ nginx-ingress controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63594846/k8s-service-lb-to-external-services-w-nginx-ingress-controller) but it didnt work.

[image]